# Seleccionar específicamente ciertas columnas con JPA-JPQL

Tags: java, jpa

Quiero traer solamente ciertas columnas de la tabla **Personas**, así como está me trae todas las columnas y las ordena por lugar.

Las columnas de la tabla son

> idPersona, nombre, apellido,edad,direccion,lugar, genero, cel

Sólo quiero que me traiga **nombre, apellido, edad, lugar y cel**

```
@Override
public List<Personas> obtenListaDePersonas(String nombre, Integer edad, Integer lugar) {

    QPersonas pathPersonas = QPersonas.personas;
    JPQLQuery<Personas> query = from(pathPersonas);
    BooleanExpression identificadorNombre   = pathPersonas.nombre.eq(nombre);  
    BooleanExpression identificadorEdad = pathPersonas.edad.eq(edad);   
    OrderSpecifier<Integer> ordenR = pathPersonas.lugar.asc();


    Predicate finalPredicate = identificadorNombre.and(identificadorEdad);
    List<Personas> listaPersonas = query.where(finalPredicate).orderBy(ordenR).fetch();

    return listaPersonas;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es que utilices un TypedQuery para personas:

```
TypedQuery<Personas> query =
      em.createQuery("SELECT nombre, apellido, edad, lugar, cel FROM personas p", Personas.class);
  List<Personas> resultados = query.getResultList();
```

También puedes resolverlo utilizando un CriteriaBuilder de JPQL:

```
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = new CriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Personas> q = cb.createQuery(Personas.class);
Root<Personas> c = q.from(Personas.class);
q.select(c.get("nombre"),c.get("apellido"),c.get("edad"),c.get("lugar"),c.get("cel")).nombre.eq....;
```

En los ejemplos anteriores no están agregados los **wheres** que veo tienes escritos, pero es muy sencillo agregarlos. Si necesitas consultar más ejemplos o documentación te recomiendo [este enlace](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select).

Ahora, si utilizas un repositorio de JPA es muy sencillo utilizar la anotación **@Query** para un método de tu interfaz y ahí escribir tu select:

```
@Query("SELECT nombre,edad,cel... from Personas p WHERE p.nombre = :nombre and p.edad = :edad")
List<Personas> findByNombreAndEdad(@Param("nombre") String nombre, @Param("edad") Integer edad);
```